# Braided category inside braided 2-category

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, monoidal-categories, higher-algebra, braided-tensor-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a semistrict braided monoidal $2$-category in the sense of [BN] (so in particular a strict $2$-category). Let $\mathcal{C}_1$ be the category of $1$-morphisms (objects) and $2$-morphisms (morphisms) in $\mathcal{C}$. (I hope that this is allowed. I think of $\mathcal{C}_1$ as a coproduct of all the Hom-categories in $\mathcal{C}$)

The semistrict monoidal structure ($\boxtimes$) on $\mathcal{C}$ induces a monoidal structure ($\otimes$) on $\mathcal{C}_1$. Let $R: \boxtimes \Rightarrow \boxtimes^{op}$ be the pseudo-natural equivalence corresponding to the braiding in $\mathcal{C}$. For $1$-morphisms $f:a \to c$ and $g:b \to d$ we can define $f\widehat{\otimes}g:=R_{c,d}\circ (f \otimes g)$ and $g\check{\otimes}f:=(g\otimes f)\circ R_{a,b}$ (analogously on morphisms in $\mathcal{C}_1$). By pseudo-naturality of $R$ we have a natural transformation $c:\widehat{\otimes} \to \check{\otimes}^{op}$ in $\mathcal{C}_1$ satisfying the hexagon equations of a braiding.

So $\mathcal{C}_1$ looks very similar to a braided monoidal category, with "the only difference" that $\widehat{\otimes} \neq \check{\otimes}$. Now, assume that $\mathcal{C}$ had enough structure, so that $\mathcal{C}_1$ is an abelian category. Is there a way of "modding out" the difference of $\widehat{\otimes}$ and $\check{\otimes}$ in $\mathcal{C}_1$? Maybe by considering some kind of coequalizer? If so, what are the conditions on $c$ for being well-defined on the new category?

[BN] Baez, Neuchl - Higher-Dimensional Algebra I: Braided Monoidal 2-Categories